# Probability of A Random Sample Meeting Criteria

Tags: r, size, probability, sample, restriction

I need to know how to find the probability that a random sample of 9 SAT‐ takers will get a group average score of 1340 and above. All I am given is the mean = 1060 and the standard deviation is 195. I am new to r and can't seem to find a tutorial online that shows me how to find this.  I have found the probability of all SAT-takers scoring 1340 and above, I'm just not sure how to add a sample size restriction.

Comment: Please try to include example code in your question that shows what you've tried so far. This question is partly about statistical theory and partly about how to use R to access properties of random distributions, do you know which value of which distribution you're trying to look up?

Comment: As @Marius said, please try to include at least some snippets of code within your question.

Answer (score 1):

The code in your deleted comment looks right: `1 - pnorm(1340, 1060, 195 / sqrt(9))`.

If individual observations are normally distributed with mean M and standard deviation S, then the sample mean of N of these observations will be normally distributed with mean M and standard deviation S / sqrt(N). `pnorm(x, M, S / sqrt(N))` gives you the probability that a value from that normal distribution will be <= x. So either

```
1 - pnorm(1340, 1060, 195 / sqrt(9))
```

or

```
pnorm(1340, 1060, 195 / sqrt(9), lower.tail = FALSE)
```

should give you the required answer. The probability is pretty low, almost 0.